# std:any throwing exception resolving function type

Tags: c++, c++17

I am running into a problem while resolving a function type from std::any.

I'm basically wrapping a function and it's initial arguments in a lambda function and calling it later point to invoke the wrapped function, but with new set of arguments. This is how the wrapped function looks like.

```
void Hello(std::string str)
{
    LOG(str);
}
```

And  I'm trying to accomplish the wrapper lambda like this: I have a lambda function that either executes the wrapped functions, and/or otherwise simply returns the wrapped function.

```
template<typename FuncName, typename... FuncArgs>
bool MMM(std::string EventName, FuncName&& EventFunction, FuncArgs&&... Args) noexcept
{
     //Storing lambda here                
     auto fPtr = std::function<std::any(bool)>([=](bool x)
                                               {
                                                    if(x){
                                                            EventFunction(Args...);
                                                    }
                                                    return (FuncName)EventFunction;
                                                });
}
```

Now when I try to invoke this lamdba like this:

```
template<typename E, typename FuncName, typename... FuncArgs>
bool AAA(E EventName, FuncName &&EventFunction, FuncArgs&&... Args)
{
    try {
    //resolving lambda and invoking it here
            auto func = std::any_cast<decltype(EventFunction)>(fPtr)(false));
            func(Args...);
    } catch (...) {
             std::cout<<"Didn't invoke function: Mismatch argument type.\n";
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm calling this function in following ways:

```
MMM(e, Hello, "Hello Florida");
MMM(e, Hello, "Hello USA");

AAA(e, Hello, "Hello World");
```

Problem:
When function AAA is called, I get an exception which says auto_cast failed to resolve the function type.

In the runtime, I see (fPtr)(false) is returning:

```
std::__1::function<std::__1::any (bool)>     Function = Hello(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)
```

while seems like decltype(EventFunction) is of type

```
void (&)(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) 0x0000000100012540
```

This seems like I'm almost close to what std::any has stored inside, but still missing out with something which I don't understand what! How do I resolve this std::any_cast mismatch?

Comment: Sorry @GuillaumeRacicot I’m not returning results, I’m only returning function every single time.

Comment: `Hello` is not a `std::function`.

Comment: I wish you have published the code in online compiler. Anyway, can you give a shot to  `std::any_cast<FuncName>(...)`?

Comment: Also, `auto func = std::any_cast<decltype(EventFunction)>(fPtr)(false));` is missing one `(`.

Comment: @ikis The "and/or otherwise" is confusing. On first read I thought "`and/or` well which is it? `otherwise` ok I guess this is a confusing way to say `else`". Now I see you meant "does X (and|or, if not,) Y". "Otherwise" denotes a mutual exclusion, which doesn't help when you mean to say "always"... I'd go with "sometimes X and always Y" if you want to be that abundantly clear. I mean, the code is totally clear in itself so I don't think this even needs that much elaboration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you need to not use arguments provided in `MMM` and override them, that hides a bug where you send the wrong arguments to `MMM`. I would suggest providing the required stuff to `MMM` so it could craft the correct set of arguments.

---

Your functions `MMM` and `AAA` both recieve the function by forwarding reference. For the call to resolve correctly, it resolve to `void(&)(std::string)` which is a reference to a function.

Then, you return that function in your lambda:

```
return (FuncName)EventFunction;
```

This will indeed cast back `EventFunction` into a function reference, but return type deduction will decay the type, so it become equivalent to this:

```
[](bool) -> void(*)(std::string) { /* ... */ }
```

Then, your other function do the same thing. If we expand the template, we get something that would look like:

```
auto func = std::any_cast<void(&)(std::string)>(fPtr)(false));
func(Args...);
```

But the type contained in the `std::any` is a pointer to a function, not a reference.

---

Even if we fix the return type, `std::any` will decay references to make it a function pointer anyway.

The solution would be to not receive the function by forwarding reference, since you're not forwarding it anyways:

```
template<typename E, typename FuncName, typename... FuncArgs>
bool MMM(E EventName, FuncName EventFunction, FuncArgs&&... Args) { /* ... */ }

template<typename E, typename FuncName, typename... FuncArgs>
bool AAA(E EventName, FuncName EventFunction, FuncArgs&&... Args) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help. This is anyways not a production code.

Comment: @ikis no problem. I've been bitten by this exact problem, that's why I'm insisting. The tone is a bit arsh anyways, I'll edit.